# How much of my Pokedex do I need to fill before talking to the Game Director?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I forget which city/hotel you meet him in, but you'll find the Game Director in place where Mr. Bonding normally is in a hotel room. He then tells you to, "come see me when you fill up the Pokedex more".

At what point is the Pokedex filled to his liking? Does this involve just seeing a Pokemon or do you have to capture/hold it too? And what do you get for completing this?

Comment: He's in the Coumarine hotel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 100% of pokemon availible in the 3 Kalos dexes, less the two Legendary Birds that aren't naitive to your world (based on your starter). He will give one diploma for each dex, then a final one when you have all three completed. The actual number of pokemon you have (including National Dex) is irrelevant.

Source:
[image]

I'm not sure if there is a fifth for collecting ALL pokemon period.

Comment: There usually is a diploma for a complete national dex; in gen 5 I believe it didn't require event-distribution-only pokemon.

Comment: @TrentHawkins possible, at the time I didn't try because it was literally impossible. With pokemon bank partially out it's now...slightly possible.